# How to non-dimensionalise a system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have these two equations

\begin{align} 
\frac{dx}{dt} &= k_1A-k_2Bx+k_3x^2y-k_4x \tag{1} \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= k_2Bx-k_3x^2y \tag{2} \end{align}

and I am suppose to non-dimensionalise them to get this result

\begin{align} 
\frac{du}{dT} &= 1-(b+1)u+au^2v \tag{3} \\
\frac{dv}{dT} &= bu-au^2v \tag{4}
\end{align}

and determine constants $a$ and $b$

Where $x$ and $y$ correspond to $u$ and $v$, respectively.

If I use $x=x^* u$, $y=y^* v$ and $T=k_4t$

I can simplfy $(1)$ to

$$ \frac{du}{dT}=\frac{k_1A}{k_4x^*} - \left(\frac{k_2B}{k_4}+1\right)u+\frac{k_3x^* y^* u^2v}{k_4} $$

and if I let $A=\frac{k_4x^*}{k_1}$, $b=\frac{k_2B}{k_4}$ and $a=\frac{k_3x^*y^*}{k_4}$ I get the desired result of $(3)$

However

when I simplify $(2)$ in the same way I get

$$ \frac{dv}{dT} = \frac{x^*}{y^*} \left(\frac{k_2B}{k_4}-\frac{k_3x^* y^* u^2v}{k_4}\right) $$

and if I sub in my values for $b$ and $a$ from above I also kind of get my desired result of $(4)$ but I have $x^*/y^*$ as a factor stuck out in front. I get

$$ \frac{dv}{dT}= \frac{x^*}{y^*}(bu-au^2v) $$

Where have I gone wrong? 
Unless I am allowed to have different $a$ and $b$ for $(3)$ and $(4)$

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on the site's formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your question would be better received with it. I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make a mistake, you just neglected to specify what $x^*$ and $y^*$ are.

To make the second equation consistent with the first, clearly you need $x^* =y^*$. Also, you need $\dfrac{k_1A}{k_4x^*}=1$, therefore $x^* = \dfrac{k_1A}{k_4}$

The last step is express $a$ and $b$ in terms of the known constants, hence

$$ a = \frac{k_3}{k_4}x^*y^* = \frac{k_3}{k_4}\left(\frac{k_1A}{k_4}\right)^2 = \frac{k_1^2k_3A^2}{k_4^3} $$

and $b = \dfrac{k_2B}{k_4}$ as before.

Hope this helps.